# Share Android Market's "Crash errors" information with developers

Tags: android, google-play, crash-reports

Android Market's "Crash errors" page is very useful for developers.

But how to use it in a team?

The crash information page should be visible by all developers, but I can't give my password as it would allow anyone to fiddle with the published APKs.

**QUESTION:** How to share the crashes reports? Is there an API or tool to export them regularly?
Copying them manually is not an option.

As a workaround, by now we are using our own crash reporting system (could have used [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/)).

Comment: yup gud question we have to implement in your code usign uncaughtException class and prompt that log to send us as a mail via intent

Comment: The built in error reporting is useless. Once a report is marked as "Old" you will never see notifications for it again even in new versions. Also users seem to think devs can tell who sent the report and ask for help in them. The report does not even include any system info. IMO you should develop your own system or be prepared for frustration.

Comment: @Kuffs: "Also users seem to think devs can tell who sent the report and ask for help in them."  Put it in the FAQ?

Comment: Because users always read those right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your own Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler and call Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler( instance ) to register it.
Thus you have all the control. It works fine if you don't have JNI parts.

It is not as easy as relying on Google Market, you have to collect information on your own and to send the report to your server, maybe send a email to your group is convenient.

In later of this year, we have seen several improvement of Market publishing interface, perhaps we should complain together in google's forum.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be the only feasable way at the moment. The advantage of using your own Exception Handler is that you can call a WebService to integrate with your own ticket system.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to share your Google Play account with other users:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/support/bin/answer.py?answer=2528691

By doing so, the other users can see that "Crash errors" page.

Comment: Great feature, but there will only be crash reports that were explicitly reported by users after the crash.
Given that not all users report crashes, you may want to opt for an in-app solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer your question (but you may not like my response): I must admit that we copy them manually out of the market into e-mails to the development team.  Given that this process is labor-intensive, we probably don't do it as often as we should.  I have not been able to find an API or tool for getting at the crash reports found in the Android Market.

I just looked at ACRA -- it looks pretty interesting.  Thanks for the link,  I will give it a try.

I was recently at AnDevCon II in San Francisco and saw http://www.crittercism.com there.  I saw a 2 minute dog-and-pony show and it looked pretty useful.  I don't know anything more about them than that ... I don't know if it is expensive for their paid version, if they're helpful, etc.  I just am aware that they exist, they have a free version, and I have them on my "look into this someday" list.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class that extends Log. You can overwrite all calls like Log.d, Log.e, Log.w etc, to post the log on a webservice. With a simple database, you can store the logs their, and share it to whoever you want.

Comment: As I wrote, I already implemented a workaround. But I would if Google offered a way to track bugs without me having to maintain special crash-handling code, that would be better.

Answer (score 0):

How about BugSense: http://www.bugsense.com/

Comment: It is another possible workaround. If I were to discuss workarounds, my preference would be ACRA because it is open source. But we are going off the topic from the question, which is about whether the Android Market has or does not have a particular feature.